# How to get value based on position of special character string in a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Col1                    Col2
Adam                    1
Barbara, Catherina      1
Barbara, Catherina      2
Adam, Catherina         1
Adam, Catherina         2
Barbara, Adam, Daniela  1
Barbara, Adam, Daniela  2
Barbara, Adam, Daniela  3
```

Need a select statement to populate Col3 like shown below

```
Col1                   Col2 Col 3
Adam                    1   Adam
Barbara, Catherina      1   Barbara
Barbara, Catherina      2   Catherina
Adam, Catherina         1   Adam
Adam, Catherina         2   Catherina
Barbara, Adam, Daniela  1   Barbara
Barbara, Adam, Daniela  2   Adam
Barbara, Adam, Daniela  3   Daniela
```

I tried using `SUBSTRING` & `CHARINDEX` but was not able to find the solution. Need a query where we can pass Col2 value and populate Col3.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Storing comma-separated strings instead of using fields and relations is a very serious design bug. You need to fix this bug instead of looking for ways to cover it up. You can use the `STRING_SPLIT` method as a quick fix until you fix the root bug.

Comment: What are the `A,B,C` values? What is the purpose of this table? There are various ways you can fix this design. Picking the correct one depends on what you want to do with them. You can use sparse columns, ie have one column per letter without wasting space for the extras. You can use an XML or JSON typed field to store multiple values (querying will be slow). If the "letters" are entities themselves, you should use one table for them, another to link them with "numbers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a Parse/Split function and a Cross Apply.

I should add that the parse could easily be migrated into the CROSS APPLY if you can't use or don't want a UDF.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Col1 varchar(25),Col2 int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
('A',      1),
('B,C',    1),
('B,C',    2),
('A,C',    1),
('A,C',    2),
('B,A,D',  1),
('B,A,D',  2),
('B,A,D',  3)

Select A.*
      ,Col3 = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Col1,',') where RetSeq=A.Col2) B
```

Returns

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       1       A
B,C     1       B
B,C     2       C
A,C     1       A
A,C     2       C
B,A,D   1       B
B,A,D   2       A
B,A,D   3       D
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

> **Just for fun, this is the NON-UDF version**

```
Select A.*
      ,Col3 = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select * From( 
                    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.Col1,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                ) C where RetSeq=A.Col2
             ) B
```

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response John. But my post was not clear earlier, i just edited it. Can you pls check now

Comment: @Vikram Still applies.

Comment: @Vikram the edit didn't change anything, just the contents. You still need a function and CROSS APPLY. And you still *shouldn't* store separated values in fields

Comment: @Vikram added a non-udf version... Cross apply only

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @Vikram Never had a doubt :)  Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

This one works only in SQL 2016 and Azure SQL DB ([more on STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx))

```
 DECLARE @DaTable TABLE (Col1 varchar(32),Col2 int)
INSERT INTO @DaTable 
VALUES
('A',      1),
('B,C',    1),
('B,C',    2),
('A,C',    1),
('A,C',    2),
('B,A,D',  1),
('B,A,D',  2),
('B,A,D',  3)

SELECT S.*
      ,Col3 = T.Value
 From  @DaTable S
 Cross Apply (SELECT * FROM 
 (Select Value, Row_Number()  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RowNum from STRING_SPLIT(S.Col1,',')) AS ss 
 where ss.RowNum = S.Col2) AS T
```

Note for Azure SQL DB:

> The STRING_SPLIT function is available only under compatibility level 130. [...]
>   Note that compatibility level 120 might be default even in new Azure SQL Databases.

Comment: [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) starts with SQL Server 2016. I submitted an edit to your answer to correct your assertion that it would work in 2012 and up.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function that gets the string (`col1`) and text index (`col2`) and returns the proper value. The query would look like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, GetElement(co1, col2) as col3
FROM table
```

The `GetElement` may use the `WHILE` loop to find the value. Pseudocode:

```
index = 1
while index < col2
charindex of the ','
if index == col2 substring to the next ',' and return
else index = index + 1 and remove the substring from beginning to the charindex of ','
```

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response owczarek. But my post was not clear earlier, i just edited it. Can you check now.

Comment: My solution should still work - the `GetElement` function looks for the index of ',' character and gets the substring. The only missing thing is that the substring from the beginning to the first ',' should be removed from the original value of `col1` in each iteration.

Comment: @owczarek you haven't posted a solution. Only a suggestion to use a `WHILE` loop. Even with running code this is the slowest way to split strings in T-SQL. There are a lot of articles and duplicate questions on how to split strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code posted by John works. So i am going with his solution.